# What is the missing step to solve the two ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading an example of an exercise of variational calculus where they get the system of equations:

\begin{equation}
F_{y'y'}y''+F_{y'z'}z''=0;\;\;F_{y'z'}y''+F_{z'z'}z''=0,
\end{equation}
where $F=F(y',z')$, and $y,\;z$ are functions of $x$. And all the functions are sufficiently smooth.

Then, in the book says: "considering $F_{y'y'}F_{z'z'}-(F_{y'z'})^2\neq 0$, we have $y''=0$ and $z''=0$". This is the part that I don't understand, so I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantity $F_{y'y'}F_{z'z'}-(F_{y'z'})^2$ is the determinant of the matrix associated to your system of equations. The authors consider this system as a linear system in the unknown $y''$ and $z''$, and the only solution is the trivial one as soon as the determinant is nonzero.